# Friend base function can access child data

Tags: c++, oop

```
class Child;

class Base
{
    friend bool friendly(const Base&,const Child&) ;
    private:
        std::string name;
    public:
        Base() {}
};

class Child: public Base
{
    private:
        int number;

    public:
        Child() {}

};



bool friendly(const Base &base, const Child &child ) 
{

    return base.name== child.name;
}
```

I didn't use another type. I am literally passing Child and Base objects to invoke a function.

```
friend(Base(),Child());
```

I can't quite get why Child can access name variable.
When accessing number member variable: {child.number} using friendly function compiler generates compile error "private data". Why i don't see that error with name variable.
They are of different types!

P.S.: i see that is quite bad design. I am concerned with this particular  behavior of C++11.

Comment: So you think that by changing the type to a more-specific type, some of the base functionality should go away? That seems incredibly counter-intuitive to me. A `Child` *is a* `Base`, so anything `friendly` can do to a `const Base &` it should be able to do to a `const Child &` -- otherwise it would get only an odd subset of the class functionality. Imagine how hard it would be if you had to make sure that odd subset was sane!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it took me a while to transition to this view. You are totally right. I was thinking only isomorphism should be responsible for such behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right that this behavior isn't particularly intuitive, especially since you normally can't access the private members of a base class. But it shouldn't be a compile error since this case is actually mentioned in the C++14 ISO standard (section 11.2.5, bolding done by yours truly):

> 5) If a base class is accessible, one can implicitly convert a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to that base
>   class (4.10, 4.11). [ Note: It follows that members and friends of a class X can implicitly convert an X* to a
>   pointer to a private or protected immediate base class of X. — end note ] The access to a member is affected
>   by the class in which the member is named. This naming class is the class in which the member name was
>   looked up and found. [ Note: This class can be explicit, e.g., when a qualified-id is used, or implicit, e.g.,
>   when a class member access operator (5.2.5) is used (including cases where an implicit “this->” is added).
>   If both a class member access operator and a qualified-id are used to name the member (as in p->T::m), the
>   class naming the member is the class denoted by the nested-name-specifier of the qualified-id (that is, T).
>   — end note ] **A member m is accessible at the point R when named in class N if**
>
> (5.1) — m as a member of N is public, or
>
> **(5.2) — m as a member of N is**
>   **private, and R occurs in a member or friend of class N, or**
>
> (5.3) — m
>   as a member of N is protected, and R occurs in a member or friend of
>   class N, or in a member or friend of a class P derived from N, where m
>   as a member of P is public, private, or protected, or
>
> (5.4) — there
>   exists a base class B of N that is accessible at R, and m is
>   accessible at R when named in class B

and it follows the above blub with this example:

```
class B;
class A {
private:
    int i;
    friend void f(B*);
};
class B : public A { };
void f(B* p) {
    p->i = 1; // OK: B* can be implicitly converted to A*,
              // and f has access to i in A
}
```

You're not using pointers, but `const` references can be implicitly converted as well.

Comment: It is funny, the standardization committee considered this case too, and i unintentionally stumbled on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is expected since `friendly` is a friend of `Base` class so it can access `Base` private members, including `name`.

Here `child.name` is still reference the `Base` private member `name`. But `number` is different, which is a private of `child` only and that is why `friendly` cannot access.